# Optimize Slow Query

Tags: mysql

I'm not good at optimizing SQL but I need this query to run as fast as possible. It will be run repeatedly on about 40 different databases by a PHP script. PHP then sorts the results chronologically.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(lastmoddate, '%a %b %D, %Y  %l:%i%p') as lastmod,
       count(*) as num_modified,
       (select count(*) from store.item) as totalitems,
       UNIX_TIMESTAMP(lastmoddate) as timestamp
FROM store.item
group by lastmoddate
HAVING lastmoddate = MAX(lastmoddate)
order by lastmoddate desc
limit 1;
```

**Explanation**

- **lastmoddate** is the the last modified date of the item record
- **count(*) as num_modified** is the number of items modified on the last update
- the **subquery** gets the total items in the table
- the **UNIX_TIMESTAMP** is probably unnecessary but I use it for sorting in the PHP later. This result is pooled with results from other databases and then sorted.

So the end goal is to get a table with the last modified date, the number of items modified on that last modified date, and the total items in the database.

The subquery could possibly be removed but it doesn't seem to affect the speed much. The other results are required. IF DATE_FORMAT or UNIX_TIMESTAMP are slow, they could removed, but they would be replaced by something in PHP which might be just as slow. (Like I said, I don't anything about optimizing SQL. I felt pretty good just getting a working query in place.)

MySQL 5.5 and PHP 5.3

Comment: Can you add (a) the output of `explain SELECT DATE_FORMAT(lastmoddate, '%a %b %D, %Y  %l:%i%p') as lastmod, count(*) as num_modified,(select count(*) from store.item) as totalitems,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(lastmoddate) as timestamp
FROM store.itemm group by lastmoddate HAVING lastmoddate = MAX(lastmoddate) order by lastmoddate desc` and/or a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) containing some of your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to get information about rows with the maximum `lastmoddate`.  Your query is aggregating *all* the data by `lastmoddate` and then choosing the last row.

Instead, do the filtering first, and then do the aggregation.  You are only getting one row on the output, so you don't even need the `group by` clause.

The approach is to calculate the maximum last mod date and total items in a subquery.  This is joined in so the data can be filtered:

```
select DATE_FORMAT(i.lastmoddate, '%a %b %D, %Y  %l:%i%p') as lastmod,
       COUNT(*) as NumModified,
       const.totalitems,
       UNIX_TIMESTAMP(i.lastmoddate) as timestamp
from store.item i cross join
     (select max(lastmoddate) as maxlastmoddate, count(*) as totalitems
     ) const
where i.lastmoddate = const.maxlastmoddate;
```

Your performance will be further improved with an index on `store.item(lastmoddate)`.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is select count(*) once and remove it as a sub query. Put it outside of your loop that executes 40 times.

Do you need the having clause? Do you get the same results without it? I think it can be put into where clause

```
WHERE lastmoddate = (select max(lastmoddate) from store.item i2)
```

Make sure you have an index on lastmoddate.